# ¿ Cómo leer valores de datos en C++?

Tags: c++, arduino

Intento reailzar un programa en el cual uno ingrese 3 valores para cada lado de un triangulo, y entonces este decida si es isosceles, escaleno o equilatero.

Apenas empiezo con esto de programacion asi que quisiera saber como debo darle instruccion al controlador para que me almacene los datos del lado a, b y c y luego los lea.

Aqui esta parte del codigo:

```
int a,b,c;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("ingrese valor de a")
  Serial.print("ingrese valor de b")
  Serial.print("ingrese valor de c")
}
void loop()
{  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leer datos, usa el flujo de entrada de datos de consola: [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin). Puedes usarlo así:

```
int a, b, c;
std::cin >> a; // Leer un entero
std::cin >> b; // Leer otro entero
std::cin >> c; // Leer un entero más
```

Comment: gracias. esa sintaxis no la conocia la verdad.

Comment: Eso es porque *apenas empiezas con esto de programación*, en realidad usar el flujo de entrada de datos desde consola es de lo más común.

Comment: si claro, lo que pasa es que yo conozco el comando "parse" que lo he usado para guardar el dato en esa variable . pero ahora queria saber si habia algun comando mas util.
como apenas empiezo con esto d la programacion pues debo empezar a entender los while, los for, swuitch case y demas. entonces trato de entender su funcionamiento con los diagramas de flujo, para luego armar el codigo.

Comment: En [tag:C++] no existen los *comandos*, dispones de funciones. No existe ninguna función en C++ estándar que reciba el nombre de "*parse*".

Comment: el parseFloat, el parseInt. mira que si los he usado. te muestro un ejemplo?

Comment: @Pablo ninguna de esas funciones existe en [tag:c++], creo que estás confundiendo [tag:c#] con [tag:c++].

Comment: aah vale. entiendo.

Comment: gracias por las instrucciones. cualquier otra duda la publicare